# Unable to alter server level role in Azure SQL DB

Tags: azure-sql-database

I am the admin of my SQL server which I have created and I am testing on altering server level roles and for that I am trying below commands. The first one returns ***executed successfully*** and the second one returns ***0***, which means I dont have that spoecific server role. can anyone explain me why this is happening. What wrong am i doing here?

```
ALTER SERVER ROLE ##MS_ServerStateReader##
    ADD MEMBER zzzsharepoint;  
GO


select IS_SRVROLEMEMBER('##MS_ServerStateReader##', 'zzzsharepoint')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/is-srvrolemember-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#return-types) behaviour:

> ### Return Types
>
> **int**
>
> | Return value | Description |
> | --- | --- |
> | 0 | *login* is not a member of *role*. In Azure SQL Database, this statement always returns 0. |
> | 1 | *login* is a member of *role*. |
> | NULL | *role* or *login* is not valid, or you do not have permission to view the role membership. |

For whatever reason, the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/security-server-roles?view=azuresql) on Azure SQL Databases suggests otherwise. It also suggests using a query to check the permissions, however, that always returns no results as well. If the `ALTER SERVER ROLE` ran successfully, I would suggest that the role *has* had the role added.